# How can I get rid of "white spaces"

Tags: java, python, string, sockets, whitespace

I'm writing server-client project. The server side is being developed in Java, and the client side in Python. Recently when I try to send a string over the socket, the server gets it with white spaces in it. Let's say I send:

```
1:user:password
```

in the server side I use a string split to convert this one string into 3, the first string (in this case "1") will tell the server what to do with the rest (the username and the password). Now the problem is that when I print what I get from the socket in the server side I get something like this:

```
1 : u s e r : p a s s w o r d
```

with white spaces between every character. I tried to use the String function `replaceAll("\\s","")` and `replaceAll("\\s+","")` but they didn't seem to work. The I used `replaceAll("\\S","k")` with a capital S, and realized that it actually showed me:

```
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
```

So I got to the conclusion that those "white spaces" aren't really white spaces, because the `\\S` replaces "anything that isn't a space character (including both letters and numbers, as well as punctuation etc)".

My question is: What are those blanks, and how can I get rid of them?

Thanks in advance. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Code that shows client writing to the socket and server reading from the socket?

Comment: I think, at first, you should find out what data your are really transferring through the socket, a string with with whitespace or without whitespace. If the python client are sending just ascii none-whitespace charactors, then there must something wrong with your java server.

Comment: I print the string I'm sending, before I send it and it's all alright, with no white spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you're sending UTF-16 (probably UTF-16LE) but decoding it as UTF-8. The "spaces" are actually nulls (zero bytes). You need to use the same character encoding on the client and the server.

Comment: I did some research, and yes, you were right, they were null characters, replaceAll("\0","") worked perfectly. THANKS A LOT.

Comment: @mapl93 that's not a proper fix, you'll still have garbage if there are any characters above 127 in the data.

Comment: Gonna leave it like that until I find the way to get the same character encoding on both, server and client.